# Cannot extend desktop to third monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi, vga

My Notebook status:

Model: **HP Pavilion 7 6b21em**
CPU:   **Intel i7 2.3 Ghz QuadCore**
RAM:   **8GB DDR5 (2x4 GB)**
GPU:   **1x Intel Integrated, 1x ATI AMD Radeon 6670M HD 2GB**
OS:    **Windows 7 64bit Ultimate**

I have switch-able graphics card however I changed the BIOS setup to Fixed so that PC and
all applications always use the better ATI AMD Radeon graphic card.

As for my outputs I have:
**1x HDMI

1x VGA**

I don't have a Display Port (I'm not sure if this is a requirement for Eyefinity).
I read on AMD site that graphic card can in fact output to both VGA and HDMI at the same time.

I have **two** external screens. I have a 24" Screen connected to my **VGA** I connected the screen and then selected Extend Desktop to this monitor under display settings.

I connected the 27" screen to the **HDMI** port the screen is detected however if I select **Extend Desktop** to this screen then it **Disconnects** the one on **VGA** and it allows me to only **Extend Desktop** to one.

This website has detailed information about my graphic card both sites say it supports Eyefinity yet I cannot find Eyefinity option under Catalyst Control Center.

I read few articles that say this is Windows fault but cant find why. Is there any software for monitor management that could solve this issue ?

Comment: Your laptop only supports 2 monitors.  This is not a Windows problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use three monitors with [AMD Eyefinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyefinity#Multi-display_technologies) at least one of them has to use the display port (either mini or full). This table is in the wikipedia article for 5800 cards but it applies to all ATI chips:

[image: table]

Your notebook may not support the required disaply output (see [AMD FAQ](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/how-to/Pages/faqs.aspx#notebook-availability)). Check with HP support but that may be the reason that it is not showing up.

> Yes! AMD Eyefinity technology support is also built into many of our
>   notebook GPUs, but it is up to the manufacturer of the notebook to
>   equip their product with the necessary display outputs.
>
> Notebooks that offer the outputs to activate AMD Eyefinity technology
>   include the Alienware M17x and the HP ENVY 17. Please note that the
>   default configurations for these notebooks may not include AMD Radeon™
>   graphics, so be sure to verify that you have selected an AMD solution
>   before checkout.